# How do I publish a physical constant

Tags: physical-constants

I think what i've found is a physical constant that is a physical quantity, universal in nature and constant in time.

**but It contrasted with a mathematical constant, which is a fixed mathematical numerical value and does not directly involve any physical measurement.**

1. Is it really necessary to consider fixed numerical value?
2. How do I publish a physical constant (that It contrasted with a mathematical constant)?

Comment: Huh?  Are you saying that you've found a constant of motion of a particular physical system?

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer sounds crazy but yes, my abstract was Accepted. (including summary of my works)

Answer (score 6):

You write a paper and send it to a reputable journal.

Then the reviewers have a go at it. Unless the editor rejects it on his or her own discretion.

If your paper is not based on solid physics and written in a language compatible with physics as we know it your odds are very, very bad.

> I've submit it in to a physics conference [...]

Be aware that conferences contributions are generally *not* peer reviewed publications and unless you were an *invited* speaker they carry approximately no weight.

Indeed there are persistent rumors that some conferences accept certain papers for comic relief.

Comment: "You write a paper and send it to a reputable journal." 
The entire article can be one page, it doesn't make any problem?

Comment: No. Short articles are accepted by very nearly every journal. Some, such as *[Physical Review Letters](http://prl.aps.org/)* specialize in short articles (thought PRL likes them to be in rapidly advancing fields).

Comment: "as we no it your odds are very, very bad." :D Yes i know

Comment: what about problem with fixed numerical value?

Comment: +1 for "rumors that conferences accept certain papers for comic relief."

Comment: Look the fine structure constant, $\alpha(k \to 0)$, is a number. That's not a problem. On the other hand, there are more cranks and crackpots out there than under-appreciated geniuses. You might want to check that you're in the latter category at some point.

Comment: @dmckee i'll ask a question about the fine structure constant,